# C# Console Application -

Tags: c#

So when I reach the end of the program where it chooses if a Pokemon appears out of nowhere it repeats the same Pokemon again and again.
e.g. I encounter Mr.Mime
I defeat Mr.Mime
I am safe
I am safe
I encounter Mr.Mime
I die
I encounter Mr.Mime
I die
I am safe
I encounter Mr.Mime
I defeat Mr.Mime

How would I stop this?

My Code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Due to dotnetfiddle.net limitations I cannot store the pokémons data to a file
        Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("|         Hello there! Welcome to the world of pokémon! My name is Oak! People call me the pokémon Prof!            |");                
        Console.WriteLine("|This world is inhabited by creatures called pokémon! For some people, pokémon are pets. Others use them for fights.|");
        Console.WriteLine("|                                  Myself...I study pokémon as a profession.                                        |");
        Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("                   |                         Would you like to start (S)?                        |");
        Console.WriteLine("                   |                                                                             |");
        Console.WriteLine("                   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        String fog = Console.ReadLine();
        String [] random = {"Pidgeot", "Jigglypuff", "Beedrill", "Caterpie", "Squirtle", "Charizard", "Charmander", "Bulbasaur", "Rattata", "Diglett", "Meowth", "Psyduck", "Dugtrio", "Magnemite", "Mr. Mime", "Gyarados", "Magikarp", "Onix", "Drowzee"};
        String [] gen  = {"♂", "♀"};
        String [] name =  {"Charmander", "Bulbasaur", "Squirtle"};
        if (fog == "s" || fog == "S" || fog == "start" || fog == "Start")

        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int HP = rnd.Next(20, 20);
            int Atk = rnd.Next(20, 20);
            int Def = rnd.Next(20, 20);
            int Lvl = rnd.Next(5, 5);
            int PN = rnd.Next(1, 721);
            Console.WriteLine("You have chosen to generate a pokémon's!");
            Console.WriteLine("    Your pokémon's Name is: " + name[new Random().Next(0, name.Length)]);
            Console.WriteLine("    Your pokémon's ㏋ is: " + HP);
            Console.WriteLine("    Your pokémon's Attack is: " + Atk);
            Console.WriteLine("    Your pokémon's Defense is: " + Def);
            Console.WriteLine("    Your pokémon's Lvl is: " + Lvl);
            Console.WriteLine("    Your pokémon's Gender is: " + gen[new Random().Next(0, gen.Length)]);
            Console.WriteLine("    Your pokémon's Pokédex number is: " + PN);

            Console.Write("Loading");
            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {

            Console.Write(".");
                Thread.Sleep(200);
            }
        Console.WriteLine(" "); 
        Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("|                       You exit the proffesors lab to journey into the world of pokemon                            |");                
        Console.WriteLine("|               Throughout your journey you may encounter wild pokemon that wish to fight and trainers              |");
        Console.WriteLine("|                                                                                                                   |");
        Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("So your journey begins... 30 paces to the gym type (s)"); // Loop 30 times with random chance of battleing
            string lf = Console.ReadLine();
            if (lf == "s" || lf == "S" || lf == "start" || lf == "Start")

            Enumerable.Repeat<Action>(() => 
            {
                int Find = rnd.Next(1, 3);
                if (Find == 1)
                {
                 Console.WriteLine("You Encountered a pokémon");
            int HP2 = rnd.Next(1, 100);
            int Atk2 = rnd.Next(1, 60);
            int Def2 = rnd.Next(1, 40);
            int Lvl2 = rnd.Next(1, 100);
            int PN2 = rnd.Next(1, 721);

            if (Atk >= Def2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You defeated " + random[new Random().Next(0, random.Length)]);
            }
            else
            {
             Console.WriteLine("Your pokémon died... Luckily a stranger appeared out of nowhere and revivded it for you so you can continue to battle");
            }
                }
                else
                {       
             Console.WriteLine("You are safe this time");
                }
            }, 30).ToList().ForEach(x => x());

        }


        else
        {
        Console.WriteLine("Sorry to see you go so soon. I hope to meey you one day ~Oak");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies on this line.

```
Console.WriteLine("You defeated " + random[new Random().Next(0, random.Length)]);
```

You are getting the same random value each time because the `Random()` constructor is based on the system time, and it is not changing enough in between calls.

See the [Random Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation quoted below

> ...However, because the clock has finite resolution, using the
>   parameterless constructor to create different Random objects in close
>   succession creates random number generators that produce identical
>   sequences of random numbers. The following example illustrates how two
>   Random objects that are instantiated in close succession generate an
>   identical series of random numbers. On most Windows systems, Random
>   objects created within 15 milliseconds of one another are likely to
>   have identical seed values.

To fix this try the following

```
Console.WriteLine("You defeated " + random[rnd.Next(0, random.Length)]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help ComradeJoecool

Comment: @Arron Davies No problem!